# On click of submit button I want to get an success alert and then clicking on OK I should get redirected to a new page for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am submitting data to the database. On successful submission, I want to display an alert stating the submission was successful and then clicking on OK I want to redirect to a new page displaying the data. I am doing this for PHP. I am not getting the success message I am being redirected to the display data page.

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    //echo "New record created successfully";
    $message = "New record created successfully";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
header("Location:displaydata.php");
exit;
```

Comment: If you're redirecting then all the HTML on the page is junked by the browser and scripts won't run. If you need someone to OK a redirect it must be on the page with the original link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("New record created successfully");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "displaydata.php";';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks I implemented your solution. and it worked as per my expectations :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant set the `header()` function under an HTML output.
Set your header Location over your output.
And for your click write it like this one:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    //echo "New record created successfully";
    $message = '<a href="myNewPage.html">New record created successfully</a>';
    echo $message;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
// header("Location:displaydata.php");// remove this one
exit;
```

Comment: I wanted to go to the new page on the click of OK button. But with this when I click OK, I am being redirected to a blank page with the hyperlink of the new page and on clicking that I reach that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using ajax

for onclick button click

```
<form id="form-search">
    <span><span class="style2">Enter you email here</span>:</span>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>
    <input type="button" value="subscribe" class="submit" id="save"/>
</form>

$(document).on('click','#save',function(e) {
    var data = $("#form-search").serialize();
    $.ajax({
         data: data,
         type: "post",
         url: "yourinsertpage.php",
         dataType: "JSON",
         success: function(data){
              if(data.message == 'Success'){
                 alert('New record created successfully');
              }else{
                 alert('Failed to create new record');
              }
         }
    });
});
```

your php file yourinsertpage.php

```
<?php

    $jsonArray = array();
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $jsonArray['message'] = "Success";
    } else {
        $jsonArray['message'] = "Failed";
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($jsonArray);

?>
```